# How can you create a function with variable return values Python?

Tags: python, function, return, arguments

I am writing a function in Python and cannot figure out the best way to implement an argument that allows the user to choose whether or not to compute an extra bit of data. It looks roughly like this

```
def function(initial_sol, tolerance, compute_extra_data = False) :
 
        solution = initial_sol
        difference = 1
        extra_data = []

        while difference > tolerance :

                newsolution = step_func(solution)
                difference = diff_func(newsolution, solution)

                if compute_extra_data :
                        extra_data.append(extra_function(newsolution))

                solution = newsolution

        return solution, extra_data
```

As `extra_function` in my actual code is a more expensive operation and gives extra information the user might not necessarily want, I wanted it to be optional. However, I'm not really sure if this is a good way of implementing that. Also I'd quite like to make it so that if `compute_extra_data = False`, the return value will just be the `solution` object, rather than a tuple with both items.

I appreciate and suggestions/ideas, thanks!

Comment: Maybe write two functions, one that does the extra data, and have the extra data one call the original function and then tack on the extra data? It entirely depends on how you want to call the functions. I think having two different functions that return different amounts of things is probably a pretty safe choice, but I'm curious as to what other solutions might be offered. Other posts about this exact question, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10223427/6273251), have some interesting suggestions, like using a `dict`. What do you think of the solutions suggested on that post?

Comment: The problem with having the extra data function call the original is that the extra data function needs to happen within the while loop. The extra data depends on all the intermediate values of `solution`, which is normally overwritten when not asking for the extra data. That post does seem to ask a similar problem, one reply says that having a function return a non-constant number of variables is a bad idea, so perhaps I'm going about this completely the wrong way.

Comment: Well if you find something that works for you, you can self-answer your question and accept the answer, if it seems like a reasonable way to solve this issue and would help future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make your function *more* general. Rather than take a boolean argument that decides whether or not to append to a list, take an arbitrary function to be called on each solution.

```
def function(initial_sol, tolerance, f=None):
    solution = initial_sol
    difference = 1
    while difference > tolerance
        newsolution = step_func(solution)
        difference = diff_func(newsolution, solution)
        if f is not None:
            f(newsolution)

        solution = newsolution

    return solution
```

Then you can call

```
s = function(x, t)
```

or

```
extra_data = []
s = function(x, lambda x: extra_data.append(extrafunction(x)))
```

---

Though repeatedly checking if `f is not None` is probably cheaper than unconditionally calling a trivial function, you could also write

```
def function(initial_sol, tolerance, f=lambda x: x):
    solution = initial_sol
    difference = 1
    while difference > tolerance
        newsolution = step_func(solution)
        difference = diff_func(newsolution, solution)
        f(newsolution)

        solution = newsolution

    return solution
```

as calling the identity function on `newsolution` is just a relatively expensive no-op.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the the output in a dictionary?

```
... 
    out ={'solution': solution }
    if compute_extra_data:
        out['extra_data']: extra_data
    return out
```